# How to generate differential flame graph of two go pprof files?

Tags: go, perf, flamegraph

I have been working on profiling a golang program and trying to generate [differential flame graph](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-11-09/differential-flame-graphs.html) of two pprof files.

Steps:

1. generate `first.pprof` file
2. improve code, then generate `second.pprof` file
3. `./stackcollapse-go.pl first.pprof > before.folded`

But it seems that the [`stackcollapse-go.pl`](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/blob/master/stackcollapse-go.pl) does not work as I expected, the `before.folded` is empty.

So what's the right way to generate differential flame graph of go program?

Answer (score 0):

`stackcollapse-go.pl` doesn't take in the raw protobuf. You need to translate your .pprof into the right textual format.

So first we get the raw data, suitable for passing to `stackcollapse-go.pl`

```
$ go tool  pprof -raw first.pprof > first.raw
```

Now we can pass it through `stackcollapse-go.pl`

```
$ ./stackcollapse-go.pl first.raw > first.collapsed
```

You can then use the flamegraph.pl script to get the final svg

```
./flamegraph.pl first.collapsed > first.svg
```